# Remove background from counters in Kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

I am using Kdenlive 17.12.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64 Bit PC.

I generated a counter via "Project" -> "Generators" -> "Counter". I checked "No background" checkbox. However, it feels that it has added a gray background. Please see below a few screenshots of the video-

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Image 3:
[image]

I want to remove the gray color background from the counter. Any suggestions, please?